# After place order moving to empty cart page. 502 bad gateway error

Tags: cart, orders, magento-1.14

We are using Magento 1.14 enterprise edition. We are moving to new AWS server.

I have place order using Guest user it is working fine. I will try to place order using register user.order was placed and it is redirect to Empty cart page.

I have checked inspect element. in Prototype.js **502 bad gateway error** occurs

Any idea on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be the issue with your nginx configuration. Please add the below in nginx configuration. Basically, it may be the problem with the header and it is unable to pass too big data. It might solve your problem.

proxy_buffers 8 16k;
proxy_buffer_size 32k;

If it doesn't workout, please check by disabling the full page cache and try again. If it works fine after disabled the full page cache, then it is something wrong with the cache storage. Please increase the storage space for cache. Also, check if APC cache enabled and increase the space.

Answer (score 1):

The actual error will be displayed if you edit app/bootstrap.php and enable display_errors

Change

```
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

To

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Then try the same scenario as before and then you will get the actual error in your Inspector

Comment: okey i will check